# Performing Selective Query for 1 Result per Row Value(with multiple Row Value(s) per Table)

Tags: sql, subquery

I am finishing up a SQL class project and am able to find the results I want, but not presented correctly, can someone offer a way to update my code to return correctly?

The task is to return the favorite genre per customer. The code below returns all purchases per customer grouped by genre and then ordered by count.   So I need only the first row per customer from this table.

I am guessing that I somehow need to nest the query that finds the grouping I have per customer and then only returns the first row or LIMIT 1

```
SELECT cust.First_Name, cust.Last_Name, genre.GenreName, COUNT(GenreID)
FROM Play_List_Invoice as invoice
JOIN Play_List_Track as track USING (trackID)
JOIN Play_List_Genre as genre USING (GenreID)
JOIN Play_List_Customer as cust USING (customerID)
GROUP BY invoice.customerID, genreID
ORDER BY invoice.customerID, COUNT(GenreID) DESC;

===RESULTS
First_Name  Last_Name   GenreName   COUNT(GenreID)
    Luís        Gonçalves   Rock         23
    Luís        Gonçalves   Latin        15
    Luís        Gonçalves   Classical    8
    Leonie      Köhler      Rock         27
    Leonie      Köhler      Blues        15
    Leonie      Köhler      Soundtrack   5
    François    Tremblay    Classical   15
    François    Tremblay    Metal       12
    François    Tremblay    Alternative & Punk  6
```

======= UPDTAE ===
I thought a Window might be it. Thanks for the tip! I do not have experience with WITH clauses I did read that they are a sub-query block with a name, or I would say a temp table.

I built:

```
with q as (
      SELECT cust.CustomerId, cust.First_Name, cust.Last_Name, genre.GenreName, COUNT(GenreID) as cnt
      SELECT cust.First_Name, cust.Last_Name, genre.GenreName, COUNT(GenreID)
        FROM Play_List_Invoice as invoice
        JOIN Play_List_Track as track USING (trackID)
        JOIN Play_List_Genre as genre USING (GenreID)
        JOIN Play_List_Customer as cust USING (customerID)
        GROUP BY invoice.customerID, genreID
        ORDER BY invoice.customerID, COUNT(GenreID) DESC
     )
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerId order by cnt desc) as seqnum
      from q
     ) q
where seqnum = 1;
```

But I get an error at the WITH.  Not sure what the issue is.  I even tried adding a a name q(topGenre) with no luck.  I tried rewriting it as a nested

```
select * from
(
    select cust.CustomerId, cust.First_Name, cust.Last_Name
        , genre.GenreName
        , row_number() over (partition by customerId order by cnt desc) as seqnum 

    from (SELECT cust.CustomerId, cust.First_Name, cust.Last_Name
        , genre.GenreName, COUNT(GenreID) as cnt
    FROM Play_List_Invoice as invoice
    JOIN Play_List_Track as track USING (trackID)
    JOIN Play_List_Genre as genre USING (GenreID)
    JOIN Play_List_Customer as cust USING (customerID)
    GROUP BY invoice.customerID, genreID
    ORDER BY invoice.customerID, COUNT(GenreID) DESC
     ) as this
) as results
where seqnum = 1;
```

But this returns a problem with "(."  I am using jupyter HUB, so the error feedback is a bit lacking.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: My sentiment exactly, but on the account of "I need a salary raise." Somebody better do it for me, and I mean fast!

Comment: Try a semicolon before the `with`. And personally I object to people referring to table expressions as "temp tables" which are a different thing entirely.

Comment: Also you have two,`select` clauses in one of those queries. Is it possible your platform doesn't like you reusing the q alias?

Comment: The inner `order by` could also be a problem. You don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
with q as (
      SELECT cust.CustomerId, cust.First_Name, cust.Last_Name, genre.GenreName, COUNT(GenreID) as cnt
      . . .  <rest of your query here>
     )
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerId order by cnt desc) as seqnum
      from q
     ) q
where seqnum = 1;
```